# Why is the PostgreSQL JDBC prepared statement threshold defaulted to 5?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

By default, the parameter statement treshold is set to 5, instead of 1. That is,

```
((PGStatement) my_statement).getPrepareThreshold()
```

always returns 5 by default.

What would be the reason for that? Why would I want not to have to use the server-side prepared statement for the first 4 times the query is executed? I fail to understand why I would ever set this to another value than 1 and why this isn't by default set to 1.

Can you explain? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Server side prepared statements consume server side resources to store the execution plan for the statement. The threshold provides a heuristic that causes statements that are actually used "often" to be prepared. The definition of "often" defaults to 5.

Note that server side prepared statements can cause poor execution plans because they are not based on the parameters passed during the prepare. If the parameters passed to a prepared statement have a different selectivity on a particular index (for example), then the general query plan of the prepared statement may be suboptimal. As another example, if you have a situation where the execution of the query is much greater than the cost to create an explain plan, and the explain plan isn't properly set due to lack of bind parameters, you may be better off not using server side prepared statements.

When the driver reaches the threshold, it will prepare the statement as follows:

```
    if (!oneShot)
    {
        // Generate a statement name to use.
        statementName = "S_" + (nextUniqueID++);

        // And prepare the new statement.
        // NB: Must clone the OID array, as it's a direct reference to
        // the SimpleParameterList's internal array that might be modified
        // under us.
        query.setStatementName(statementName);
        query.setStatementTypes((int[])typeOIDs.clone());
    }
```

The statement name is sent as part of the wire protocol, which tells Postgres to prepare it server side.

Comment: So in essence if we use prepared statement functionality (Connection.prepareStatement(...) function) for one-time queries, we are only profitting from the benefits of parameter binding, no SQL injection risks, and so on? Does this mean that the JDBC driver will translate this prepared statement to a regular statement to 'fake' this parameter binding the first 4 times? If so, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: It doesn't fake the binding... the only difference is whether a name is attached to the query when sent to the server or not (see my edit in the answer).

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Naming the query will result in saving the execution plan at the server. Since this is costly, this is by default only done once the query has been executed 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

5 was picked at random and can be configured by the user.
Additionally to using resources on the server a named statement will require an extra round trip by the driver to describe the parameters for the statement. This is the primary reason the driver does not use a named statement by default.